# Inserting base64 to sqlite in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, base64

In my Phonegap Project I need to store an image to sqlite by converting image to base64 string. Image size is 160kb. Image is not getting inserted. Is it because of the size?

```
var encodeImageUri = function(imageUri, callback) {
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    c.width = this.width;
    c.height = this.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    if(typeof callback === 'function'){
        var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        callback(dataURL.slice(22, dataURL.length));
    }
};
img.src = imageUri;
```

};

```
encodeImageUri('http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/030883e15a374ba397b57b8d4bf1033e.png', function(base64String)
                                  {

                                  populateBannerImage(base64String);

                                    });
```

In populateBannerImage , I m inserting base64 to db.

```
function populateBannerImage(imageData)
```

{

```
 db.transaction(function(tx) {

                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO banners (id, name , banner_image_mobile, banner_image_mobile_ar, banner_image_tablet, banner_image_tablet_ar,banner_heading,banner_heading_ar, banner_title, banner_title_ar, url, url_ar, status, created_date, modified_date ) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',[JSONData.banner_id, JSONData.banner_name,JSONData.banner_image_mobile,JSONData.banner_image_mobile_ar, imageData, JSONData.banner_image_tablet_ar,JSONData.banner_heading,JSONData.banner_heading_ar, JSONData.banner_title, JSONData.banner_title_ar, JSONData.url, JSONData.url, JSONData.status, JSONData.created_date, JSONData.modified_date]);

                });
```

}

ImageData to db. I m new to this. Please help me

Comment: No! SQLite supports by default [~1GB](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) fields. Note you can save raw bytes (in a BLOB) instead of Base64 , saving 25% space. Problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: type I given is CHAR. First I convert Image uri to Base64 then inserting to db. How to convert Base64 to raw byte.
Please see the code.......

encodeImageUri('http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/030883e15a374ba397b57b8d4bf1033e.png', function(base64String)
                                      {
                       
                                      populateBannerImage(base64String);
                                      
                                        });

Comment: Something is not correct: do you store URI or image data? If URI, why convert to Base64? If data, how do you get it before converting to Base64?

Comment: in populateBannerImage insert image to db

Comment: Sorry, if I confused you. I could convert image to base64. I just edited my question.

Comment: Ok, it seams [tag:cordova] use base64 to handle binary data... Problem should be in  `INSERT`. Post your `populateBannerImage` function and error log!

Comment: Did you try using `errorCallback` to check result?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Got this error message. "the SQLTransactionCallback was null or threw an exception"

Comment: I'm really out of my bounds, but I would say that you must also specify `transactionCallback` before `errorCallback`.

Comment: Okay, But I think its javascript callback issue. Before getting the base64 string from the corresponding function, inserting finished. I m not an expert in javascript.